# Android Geocoder setLocal English but in italy don't works

Tags: android, maps, google-geocoder

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(gEngine, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I want retrive info in only english. I set in geocoder Locale.ENGLISH but if i get more results I have this locality, adminarea, country ...

```
Milano, Lombardia, Italy
Milano, Lombardia, Italy
Milan, Lombardy, Italy
Milano, Lombardia, Italy
Milan, Lombardy, Italy
```

locality and adminarea is in italian in few result... i need english

Comment: I dont unsertand what did you want to do. ı have to tell something. you have to add your code all activities create if you want to run only english

Comment: I want retrive info in only english. I set in geocoder Locale.ENGLISH, but if i get 10 results i have this locality, adminarea, country ...[ Milano, Lombardia, Italy]             
[ Milano, Lombardia, Italy ]           
[Milan Lombardy Italy ]           
[Milano Lombardia Italy ]           
[Milan Lombardy Italy ] locality and adminarea is in italian in few result